# Streaming webcam using command line in vlc on Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, vlc

I want to create a batch file. so i can execute file which stream my webcam using vlc.

I try following code

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/}``
```

but not working ..

Please help

Comment: what does "but not working.." mens? errormessage?

Comment: that code just execute VLC.EXE..
i think video and audio path is required in :sout but i don't know how to add that paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss the videofile...

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "C:\PathToMyVideo\myVideofile.mpg":sout=#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=2000,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8080/}
```

Comment: Thanks, But actually there is no video file. I am streaming my capture device. so there is a video and audio link from webcam . I don't know the syntax to add those paths

Comment: or when you have conected with USB... there is a good tutorial... http://breakthrusoftware.com/html/onlinedocs/kb/videomill/VLC.html (but whitout start from console)